# Deploy django with zappa doesn't working

Tags: zappa

I tried deploy django with zappa many times,
get following error.

```
{
    "message": "An uncaught exception happened while servicing this request. You can investigate this with the `zappa tail` command.", 
    "traceback": [
        "Traceback (most recent call last):\n", 
        "  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 441, in handler\n    response = Response.from_app(self.wsgi_app, environ)\n", 
        "  File \"/tmp/pip-build-hvU2Xn/Werkzeug/werkzeug/wrappers.py\", line 865, in from_app\n", 
        "  File \"/tmp/pip-build-hvU2Xn/Werkzeug/werkzeug/wrappers.py\", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app\n", 
        "  File \"/tmp/pip-build-hvU2Xn/Werkzeug/werkzeug/test.py\", line 871, in run_wsgi_app\n", 
        "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable\n"
    ]
}
```

Need some help, Seriously.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Try the latest version of zappa in the docker version https://github.com/danielwhatmuff/zappa

Answer (score 1):

When I get errors related to `werkzeug wrapper` it is usually because my packages were not installed in my virtual environment.

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install Django
pip install zappa
# or with a requirements.txt file
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then run the `zappa` deploy commands.

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking at the real error. Do as it says "You can investigate this with the `zappa tail` command".

I'd run `zappa tail --since 1m` in one window and `zappa update` in another, you'll see the real exception there.

Comment: I am having the same error and `zappa tail` shows `[1504818072948] 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: What libraries are you using? Are you rolling your own WSGI application? If there's no other errors, I believe this is telling you that Zappa couldn't find the entrypoint to the WSGI app.